# Facing ValueError in max ()

Tags: python

I am troubling with the code section given below.. when I execute it, I get value error given below.

```
Segmask = result2
        box=[]
        [liver_res, num] = measure.label(result1, return_num=True)
        region = measure.regionprops(liver_res)
        for i in range(num):
            box.append(region[i].area)
        label_num = box.index(max(box)) + 1
        liver_res[liver_res != label_num] = 0
        liver_res[liver_res == label_num] = 1

Value error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/gdrive/My Drive/LiTS/test.py", line 122, in <module>
    predict(args)
  File "/content/gdrive/My Drive/LiTS/test.py", line 91, in predict
    label_num = box.index(max(box)) + 1
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. You on the other hand aren't being very clear about what you expect this code to be doing.

Comment: You can reproduce this error simply as `my_array = []; max(my_array)`. So what is likley occuring is that your for loop isnt iterating and the value of num is 0, there for box never has any elements in it, hence an emptry sequence is being passed to max which raises an error